# "Powershell: The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered" after installing SP (not configured)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have 2 servers (Hyper-V clients) with Windows 2012R2 and  SharePoint 2013 installed.

On the first server, I am installing SP and doing nothing with him. With second server, I am testing SP.

Many times configuring farm and doing "revert" on hyper-v host machine when in client machine something wrong in my work with farm, and I am starting work with previous snapshot. But once my SP console doesn't work and wrote me:

> **Powershell:** "The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered".

Remember, this SP is not configured, he hasn't any DB. This problem is on 2 servers! I am trying use revert, but always this error. What happened? How to resolve?

Comment: Run Powershell as elevated? If it's not elevated, you can't get access to local farm.

Comment: Yes, powershell run as elevated, but nothing changes. user is administrator of computer and hes installed SP.

Comment: Hmm. Doing revert on one VM without taking the domain into account can make your Sharepoint lose AD configuration. Probably your other VM has stuffed your AD with configuration data including DB info, and then you try accessing local farm (aka DB) while there's no DB anymore. Check if there's Sharepoint configuration in your AD, if there is, remove and retry.

Comment: Im thinking in this way, but where are i can find Sharepoint configuration in AD? And this is dangerous becouse im have production server SP 2010 in this domain.

Comment: This issue may also occur if there is a new .Net framework update applied and affect the Power Shell version. more details at  [The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered in SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/the-local-farm-is-not-accessible-cmdlets-with-featuredependencyid-are-not-registered/)

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is because of a permission issue against the config database.

If you go in to your DB select the `_config` DB and check out the permissions for the user you are logged in as you will probably see you do not have shell access.

Check [This](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2014/01/02/fix-for-the-local-farm-is-not-accessible-cmdlets-with-featuredependencyid-are-not-registered.aspx) out

You could always try Running powershell as another user much like one of the comments suggest but you will need to know who to run it as.

Cheers

Truez

Comment: In my question im wrote: "SP just installed, not configured", I havent any database on this step.
Im try another user (local administrator) - nothing changes.

This computers in domain, and im do all the actions from the domain user, who administrator on this computers.

Comment: Do you have a central administration?

Comment: Nope.
But im try to install central administration througth SP master and hes create DB and PS console worked. BUT i dont want install central administration througth SP master (and i did at not long time ago). 
Also, after this im again trying revert SP machine (power off, deleting DB from SQL server, revert) and ... again my problem. And i forgot with this problem im take error "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed." and resolve it with computer out and in domain.